# How to resolve this error on frontend : "Invalid header value detected"

Tags: magento2, error, reports

I am finding the following error on front-end after running the command
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in `putty`

```
There has been an error processing your request    
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
```

After checking the var/report/1036366111049 file I am getting the following error :-

```
    a:4:{i:0;s:29:"Invalid header value detected";i:1;s:1881:"#0 vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/AbstractLocation.php(48): Zend\Http\Header\GenericHeader::splitHeaderLine('Location: https...')
    #1 vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(448): Zend\Http\Header\AbstractLocation::fromString('Location: https...')
    #2 /home/superadmin/public_html/FACE/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(352): Zend\Http\Headers->lazyLoadHeader(0)
    #3 vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(93): Zend\Http\Headers->current()
    #4 var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(310): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendHeaders()
    #5 /vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(128): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendHeaders()
    #6 var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(336): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->send()
    #7 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(44): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->send()
    #8 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendResponse()
    #9 var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
    #10 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(259): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
    #11 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
    #12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/FACE/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/FACE/index.php";}
```

Please help me how to resolve this Error.